# Android video stream capture for AR

Tags: android, video-streaming, augmented-reality, android-video-player

I would like to be able to capture the video from an android phone camera, and then process this video. Processing involves adding a layer of AR to the live stream. Is this possible on android? Pretty sure it should be.

I have looked at the android site [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html] but this seems to be concerned with video capture and storage. I would like to be able to play with the video pre-storage.

Thanks,

Comment: You can find a answer for your problem [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065334/stream-video-to-web-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how real-time you want the data to be, you can potentially use [`Camera.setPreviewCallback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) with [`Camera.PreviewCallback#onPreviewFrame`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) to listen for preview frames coming from the camera.

An example on usage can be found in the [ZXing source code](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android) (a.k.a. Barcode Scanner) source code.

Comment: Roman,

Thanks very much for the reply. I will look into this but the return of a byte[] seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am studying the problem. Personally I think it is better to use video streams from Android MediaRecorder, rather than from previewPicture, because the latter is just some samples, with lower frame rate.