# Stream video to web in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, video-capture

I want to make an android app which can stream video to the web. I know how to record a video in android but don't know how to stream it to the web. I don't want to store this video to the sd card of the phone but I want it to be stored on the web. For that purpose I am planning to use asp.net web service.

Comment: Did you manage to add a layer on a streaming video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `onPreviewFrame` method of the `Camera` to achieve this. I just send the `byte[]` to the server and convert this data to a valid video/image format on the server. For the server, I used [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/).

Comment: hi vinod maurya...can u pls explain me in more detail how u did live video streaming in android..pls i will be greatly oblige to your

Comment: sure, I will separate the streaming code from my original project and explain it in my answer. Just give me 1-2 days.

Comment: +1 for remembering and answering your question after approximately 3 months